# Confused about WCF and ASP.NET MembershipProvider Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net, wcf, forms-authentication, membership-provider

Reading, watching videos, googling around, I am very confused about how to connect WCF with an ASP.NET app that uses forms authentication with a MembershipProvider. I've seen a suggestion where you have use a specialized service host, explained here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398990.aspx][1]):

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" 
                Service="System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService" %>
```

I've also seen an implementation that does it in a ServiceFactory:

```
ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost (typeof(MyServices), baseAddresses)
                          {
                             Credentials =
                             {
                                UserNameAuthentication =
                                   {MembershipProvider = Membership.Provider}
                             },
                             Authorization =
                             {
                                PrincipalPermissionMode = PrincipalPermissionMode.UseAspNetRoles
                             }
                          };

serviceHost.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]);
```

Both methods are confusing to me. For the first one, where do I specify my specific service contract and what if I have several services? The second method is clearer. But in both cases what happens if I try to access a forms authentication protected directory, for instance, mysite/admin/myservice.svc? Does the security mechanism kick in on both the Service and directory access level? What if you wanted to use two different membership providers, one for the file access and another for the actual WCF service? This wouldn't be an unusual scenario.

Any help would be great, feeling dazed and confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beauty of WCF is that this can be done in the web.config or via code-behind (whichever is your preference). The authentication for WCF is handled in the  behavior. I've found it much easier to use the web.config for my bindings. Here is a quick example of how the server configuration would look.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
   <wsHttpBinding> <!-- required since BasicHttpBinding has no security model -->
     <binding name="FormsAuthProvider">
       <security mode="Message">
         <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredentials="true"/>
       </security>
     </binding>
   </wsHttpBinding>
 </bindings>
 <behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="FormsAuthProvider">
        <serviceCredentials>
          <usernameAuthetication userNamePasswordValidationMode="MembershipProvider" membershipProviderName="formsProvider"/>
        </serviceCredentials>    
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>    
  </system.serviceModel>  
  <system.web>
    <membership>
      <providers>
         <add name="formsProvider" type="..."/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
  </system.web>
```

This example configuration works on message security - not transport security (security mode). If you had directory security on the service itself it would be required to have been authenticated prior to consuming the service endpoint.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730301.aspx) doesn't have this option listed as a common security scenario for some reason.

Comment: i do believe this is the first time i have ever seen the phrase "The beauty of WCF"

Comment: I noticed in the example I gave, the security was set at the ServiceHost level, but in your example it's at the binding level.  What's the difference?  As for web.config, this is very hard to deploy, especially if you have to instruct your users to do it.

Comment: There is no difference between the bindings in the web.config vs. the ServiceHost configuration. It is one in the same. The bindings in the web.config are more flexible since they can apply to all endpoints (wsHttpBinding, basicHttpBinding, etc.) instead of just a service host with a single endpoint (more scope control).